# MVC Master Detail Saving Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, master-detail

Im trying to learn some MVC, therefore I created a webpage with a master/detail saving form. My problem is:
I get this error message:

```
SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (XHR): POST
```

when I add `foreach()` in the controller action to save the details.
Without `foreach()` its working fine.

Im using a database first approach.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TicketMaster] (
[TicketID]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Titel]               VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TicketID] ASC)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TicketDetails] (
[TicketDetailsId] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[TicketID]        INT          NOT NULL,
[ItemName]        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TicketDetailsId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_TicketDetails_TicketMaster] FOREIGN KEY ([TicketID])REFERENCES [dbo].[TicketMaster] ([TicketID])
);
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class TLSModel 
{           
       public string Titel { get; set; }
       public List<TicketDetail> TicketDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var list = [];
  $('#add').click(function () {
    list.push({
        ItemName: $('#ItemName).val().trim()          
    });
    $('#ItemName).val('').focus();
    GeneratedItemsTable();
});
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var data = {
        Titel: $('#Titel').val().trim(),            
        TicketDetails: list           
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Ticket/Create',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify( data ),
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (d) {
            if (d.status == true) {
                alert('Successfully done.');
                list = [];
                $('#Titel').val('');
            }
            else {
                alert('Failed');
            }
            $('#submit').val('Save');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error. Please try again.');
            $('#submit').val('Save');
        }
    });
});
function GeneratedItemsTable() {
 ...some Code...
}
});
```

Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult Create (TLSModel T)
    {
        bool status = true;            
        TicketMaster ticket = new TicketMaster { Titel = T.Titel };
        foreach(var i in T.TicketDetails)
        {
            ticket.TicketDetails.Add(i);
        }
        db.TicketMasters.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just fixed my problem. Therefore I deleted and recreated the ADO.Net Entity Data Model. Seems that I somehow messed things up in there.

Still many thanks to mateudu for your help, really appreciated that.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to add `ticket` to your `db`, and then run `foreach` loop. Finally try to save, because that entity should be added to your `DbContext` before `TicketDetails`.
Your controller code should look like this:

```
public JsonResult Create (TLSModel T)
{
    bool status = true;            
    TicketMaster ticket = new TicketMaster { Titel = T.Titel };
    db.TicketMasters.Add(ticket);
    foreach(var i in T.TicketDetails)
    {
        ticket.TicketDetails.Add(i);
    }    
    db.SaveChanges();
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };            
}
```

BTW: Why don't you use `async` methods, like `db.SaveChangesAsync()`?

Comment: Could you post the working code? Maybe try first to save the ticket object, and then get this entity back from your context using db.TicketMasters.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Titel==T.Titel). Next, run foreach loop and try SaveChanges() again.

Comment: still getting the same error.
Just delete the foreach loop and its working fine except that its not saving the detail information